# Help filling out "info.plist" file

Tags: iphone, xcode, info.plist

I'm ready to submit my first app to the App Store, however I'm having trouble filling out some of the "Info.plist" fields. I don't want my app to be rejected because I did this wrong.

These are the fields I'm having trouble with:

**Executable file,
 Bundle identifier,
 Bundle name and Bundle creator OS Typecode**

Can you put anything on these fields or are you suppose to use certain values or names such the "App ID" given by Apple for your application?
I already have an "App ID" for my app but I don't have a website for my app yet.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with `Hotpaw2's` answer:

> Bundle creator is an obsolete
>   4-character field for iOS apps. I
>   leave it blank with no problems.

*Leave this blank, as stated. (I used to write `APLM` for "Apple Mobile").*

> Bundle name is what appears under your
>   icon. Make sure it fits under the
>   icon. It has to be not misleadingly
>   different from your app's name.

*For example, I have an app called `Jewish Music Stream`. I put `JewishMusic` in this field. It fits and it is similar to my app name. If I wrote `Death Metal`, I may have been rejected because that genre has nothing to do with what's offered in the app. If I would have written `Jewish Music Stream`, it would have appeared as `Jewi...Stream` or something like that.*

> Bundle ID is your unique reverse DNS.
>   You don't have to have a web site for
>   this particular app. But your
>   registered web domain and a unique app
>   name (or web page) would be
>   appropriate for this field (reversed
>   of course). It has to be compatible
>   with you provision (which might be
>   wildcarded). The Bundle ID should not
>   have the wildcard.

*Mine was `com.yetanotheriphoneapp.jms`*

> The restriction on product file name
>   is no spaces or special characters.
>   Nobody sees it, so it can be almost
>   anything (unique for your apps and
>   non-misleading). I've had old obsolete
>   project names on mine, but the apps
>   were still accepted.

*The truth is that people can see your app name if they have Xcode, or if they look into the iTunes folder for the actual binaries. This makes no difference, but it's an interesting habit - naming your binaries.*

Good luck to you and may you make many successful apps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! But what if I don't have a registered web domain? What do I put on the Bundle ID? Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need a registered domain. It just needs to be consistent with whatever you set up in your app id. *Example:* `com.nonexistantdomain.appname`

Answer (score 2):

Bundle creator is an obsolete 4-character field for iOS apps.  I leave it blank with no problems.

Bundle name is what appears under your icon.  Make sure it fits under the icon.  It has to be not misleadingly different from your app's name.

Bundle ID is your unique reverse DNS.  You don't have to have a web site for this particular app.  But your registered web domain and a unique app name (or web page) would be appropriate for this field (reversed of course).  It has to be compatible with your provision (which might be wildcarded).  The Bundle ID should not have the wildcard.

The restriction on product file name is no spaces or special characters.  Nobody sees it, so it can be almost anything (unique for your apps and non-misleading).  I've had old obsolete project names on mine, but the apps were still accepted.

Comment: I thought that the "Bundle display name" is what appears under the icon and not "Bundle name".